# LEFT JOIN - List all chefe sellers and their sales and value

Tags: mysql, left-join

In the following example for demonstration I get the sum of sales value per seller

tab_sellers:

```
id_seller | seller | chefe
   1         John     bart
   2         Marie    bart
   3         Jamie    lucas
   4         Arnold   lucas
   5         peter    Homer
```

tab_sales:

```
id | sales | seller | value
1     BMW       1      100
2     FORD      1      200
3     FIAT      2      300
4     FORD      2      400
5     FORD      3      400
```

And I count sales, with the following query:

```
SELECT tsl.sellers, 
       SUM(ifnull(ts.value,0)) AS value_sales, 
       COUNT(ts.sales) AS sales_number
FROM tab_sellers tsl
LEFT JOIN tab_sales ts ON  tsl.id_seller = ts.seller
GROUP BY tsl.seller
```

The problem is that I need to get the sum of the sales and the values in relation to each chefe (the table is built according to the example of tab_sellers and I can't change that).

Expected outcome:

```
chefe | sales | value
 bart     4      1000
 lucas    1      400
 homer    0      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on right direction, just if you want

> get the sum of the sales and the values in relation to each chefe

then use `group by tab_sellers.chefe`

```
 select tab_sellers.chefe, count(tab_sales.sales) as sales , coalesce(sum(tab_sales.value), 0) as summ
 from tab_sellers
 left join tab_sales
 on tab_sellers.id_seller = tab_sales.seller
 group by tab_sellers.chefe
 order by summ desc
```

Comment: Thanks Dimglod and OtoShavadze. I will try to implement this solution in my query

Answer (score 1):

No problem, just group by chefe instead of seller:

```
SELECT tsl.chefe, 
       SUM(ifnull(ts.value,0)) AS value_sales, 
       COUNT(ts.sales) AS sales_number
FROM tab_sellers tsl
LEFT JOIN tab_sales ts ON  tsl.id_seller = ts.seller
GROUP BY tsl.chefe
```